# Plugin Not Registered Error (SBPLLatticePlanner)

Tags: ros, navigation, plugin, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I managed to compile [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner) under hydro. Its plugin is registered and when running

```
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core
```

outputs

```
sbpl_lattice_planner /home/yan/straight_nav/src/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/bgp_plugin.xml
```

However, when I'm running the navigation, I get the following error, showing the plugin is not registered:

```
[ INFO] [1417160047.298448917]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1417160047.349348370]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1417160047.435368190]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1417160047.667259434]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1417160047.782624823]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1417160047.788759929]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1417160047.819685654]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1417160047.935887527]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[FATAL] [1417160048.000805977]: Failed to create the SBPLLatticePlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class SBPLLatticePlanner with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner navfn/NavfnROS
[move_base-6] process has died [pid 20298, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base odom:=shark/odom __name:=move_base __log:=/home/yan/.ros/log/e734a656-76d0-11e4-95d8-0024e832832e/move_base-6.log].
log file: /home/yan/.ros/log/e734a656-76d0-11e4-95d8-0024e832832e/move_base-6*.log
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198514/plugin-not-registered-error-(sbpllatticeplanner)/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works for me on Hydro. Are you sure you've sourced the setup.bash for the workspace containing sbpl_lattice_planner before you launch move_base?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-30**:
I guess the OP solved this, because he followed up with a question indicating that SBPL is working: http://answers.ros.org/question/198586/sbpllatticeplanner-and-pose_follower/

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-30**:
Yes, Thanks @ahendrix . I marked your comment as the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to run "rospack profile" to force a recheck of all package.xmls and find the plugin.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1